# How to use sklearn’s FeatureHasher on dask daframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, dask, jupyter-lab

The dataframe:

```
  gender    category    subcategory  item_brand   item_NWT  item_price
   Women    Outerwear     Jacket      J. Crew        NWT       22.0
   Women    Outerwear     Jacket      Talbots        NWT       50.0
   Women    Outerwear     Jacket      J. Crew        NWT       100.0
```

I intend to use FeatureHasher because of it's high cardinality it is not a good approach to go for oneHotEncoding; the problem is, I don't know how to use this approach on dask dataframes.

On the screenshot, after loading the data I try to hash the features but the array I get is really short, I guess it is because of the n_features, does anyone knows how to perform FeatureHasher in dask dataframes?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just looking for an integer representation of the unique values, you could use Categorical for that.

```py
cat_columns = ["gender", "category", "subcategory", "item_brand", "item_NWT"]
df = df.categorize(columns=cat_columns)
```

Once these columns are a known categorical type, you can access the codes:

```py
df["item_brand"].cat.codes
```

See the dask.dataframe docs on [Categoricals](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/dataframe-categoricals.html), [`dask.dataframe.DataFrame.categorize`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.categorize.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.categorize) and the `dask.Series.cat` accessor [API docs](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/dataframe-api.html#categorical-accessor) for more information.